# How do I get IntelliJ to create a ".ipr" file for me?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I created a project and configured everything so that it properly loads my modules, compiles and runs in tomcat. But when I then copy it to another computer and try to open it as a project, it doesn't have anything set up because there's no ".ipr" file. How do I create this?

I cannot find the setting anywhere in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

The current versions of IntelliJ IDEA prefer use of an `.idea` folder within a project to [store its settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/project-and-ide-settings.html). Older versions (much older by this point) would use a `.ipr` file, or would support either and let one convert between the formats.

If you move a project, including its `.idea` folder, to another system, it should have all of the same project-specific settings.